# Spring Jpa -repository call with date

Tags: hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa

```
 filterSearchCriteria1.add(new FilterCriteria<java.time.LocalDate>("Schedule Date","=", LocalDate.now()));

        Iterable<TransactionDbo> results  = TransactionRepository.findAll(filterSpecification.getSpecifications(filterSearchCriteria1));
```

Help required...getting the below error,how to resolve?
findAll is the repository call I am making...
Model has the date defined as Local date. jpa
Specification works with integer or string but fails with date.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2018-07-31] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-07-31] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before**

```
predicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(i.get(column),  param.getValue().toString());
```

**After**

```
predicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(i.get(column), (Comparable) param.getValue());
```

Getting rid of the toString and using Comparable helped me resolve the issue.